# Getting Blank/Null parameter value in API controller after passing from Angular2 typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

Please refer below code: it is calling api but getting all parameters to null
login object contains - email,password,firstname,lastname

```
LoginSubmit(login){
        let url = API_ENDPOINT + "/Account/LoginMobile";        
        let body = JSON.stringify({login});
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        return this.http.post(url, body, {headers})
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get `Blank`/`Null`? On the server?

Comment: Yes I am getting null values on server I.e controller

Answer (score 0):

The call should look like

```
return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers})
```

instead of

```
return this.http.post(url, body, {headers})
```

Comment: sorry that was typo, I have corrected it. but issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You should  try to return the data object:

```
return this.http.post(url, body, {headers})
            .map(response => response.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: I will check this solution